# Build process - best practice for MEAN (Mongo, Express, Angular, Node) Stack?

Tags: gruntjs, mean-stack

I am working building a web application on the MEAN stack. I have got the basic skeleton of the application, the main parts of which are as follows:

```
app-folder
    public
        js
            app.js
            controllers.js
            directives.js
            services.js
        css
        bower_components
            angular
            bootstrap
            jquery
            <other libraries>
    node_modules
    views
        partials
    tests
        unit-tests
        e2e-tests
    app.js
    Gruntfile.js
    package.json
    bower.json
    karma.conf.js
    e2econf.js
```

Now, I am looking to make a production build process which will automate all tasks. These are:
1. download the repository from github
2. install all libraries (npm install and bower install)
3. concat all js files and uglify them
4. Delete all the dist files that are copied as part of the npm and bower commands.
5. replace the script tag in index html to point to the concatenated and uglified js above.
6. start the node server

Is this the right approach? Can step 1 and 2 be achieved with grunt? What grunt modules can I use to achieve step 3 onwards?

Answer (score 0):

You can do all this steps with grunt (or gulp), also there are famous packages that do what do you are saying.

3-1. [grunt-contrib-concat](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat)

3-1. [grunt-contrib-uglify](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify)

4. [grunt-contrib-clean](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-clean)
5. I think some grunt-module is doing this for me, but i don't know
6. You can start a server with grunt, but in production i think it's better to use a tool like forever, pm2, etc.

My suggestion is to make a dummy project with yeoman ([angular-fullstack generator](https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack)) and see the enormous and useful Gruntfile.js it generates. It have most of the operations you want to do and works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do all this with grunt and gulp, but another interesting option is Docker (depending of course on situation).

If you use the yeoman meanjs (http://meanjs.org/) generator you get both the grunt and docker for free.